# Bug in IE with tooltip / title for options in a select drop down box?

Tags: jquery, html

Has anyone else seen a bug in IE (11) where the tooltip/title text only pops up for options that are below the currently selected option? Anything above, even though it has title text, will not pop up.

Work arounds with jquery? I've tried assigning a class to the options and then giving that class a mouseover event, and also tried a click event, but I could not get them to fire off.

I'm limited to IE development for a government contract, so workarounds or functionality for other browsers will not help.

I've also tried qTip and the built in tooltip libraries in jquery ui with no success.

Is this a bug in the way IE handles options and some of the attributes/properties that are assigned?

Answer (score 1):

IE11 rendering of SELECT is weird. I suggest converting it into a more presentable control via  [SELECT2 jQuery plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). You can format it to whatever you like and with a little bit of additional code like:

```
function format(item) {
    return "<div title ='" + item.element[0].title + "'>" + item.text + "</div>";
}


$('select').select2(
     { 
       formatResult: format,
       formatSelection: format
     }

 );
```

you can add original "title" tooltips to it. Here's a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r1bzb9y3/